# How to get inserted records newly in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to select newly inserted records in the data table in SQL server,

My select statement is running every minute and I want to select newly inserted records only

Comment: How do you insert the records in your database ?

Comment: Did you even try anything by yourself? Show what did you try and read [how to ask questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show the sql you are trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your records to datatabse with linq you can get the last inserted like that:

```
var result = (from t in MyDB  
      orderby t.ID descending
      select t.ID).First();
```

Comment: how do you know he is using `EntityFramework`? And he says record**s**